# Different differential methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -t^3y^2-ty^2$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{sin t}{cos t+10}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} -\frac{3y}{x} =x^3cosx$$

Which differential method should be used for each equation?

Comment: Any thoughts yourself? You could for example tell us which methods you know of and what you think of applying them to each of the example you give. If we just give you answers you will not learn anything.

Comment: Separable; immediate; linear non-constant coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to solve the following types in general:

**Separable differential equations:** A [separable differential equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx) is one which can be written in the form:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)g(y)$$
This can be solved by dividing both sides by $g(y)$ and integrating both sides with respect to $x$. Now, since they are separated, they can be integrated on both sides:
$$\int \frac{1}{g(y)}~dy=\int f(x)~dx$$

**Linear differential equations:** A [linear differential equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx) is one which can be written in the form:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)$$
This can be solved using the [Integrating Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) $\mu(x)=e^{\int P(x)~dx}$, and then multiplying both sides by it. Then, the reverse product rule can be applied and both sides can now be integrated.

I will leave you to identify the type of differential equations you have. I've mentioned all of the types you have on your question.

Comment: For the separable equation you aren't really multiplying by $dx $ ( though I know that's how it's commonly thought of) I think stressing that you are integrating both sides wrt  $x $ is conceptually important and helps demystify the when is $dy/dx $ a fraction debate.

Comment: @Karl Yes, that is indeed true, thanks. I've edited my post.

Comment: (+1) it is a nice answer it's just something that confused me for ages.

Answer (score 0):

hint: write the first equation in the form
$$\frac{dy}{y^2}=(-t^3-t)dt$$ with $$y\ne 0$$
for the second you can integrate with respect to $t$: $$x \left( t \right) =-\ln  \left( \cos \left( t \right) +10 \right) +{
\it \_C1}
$$
for the last one you must solve the homogeneous equation and for the particular equation make the ansetz $$y_p=Ax^3\sin(x)+Bx^3\cos(x)$$

Comment: could you explain where all this wisdoms come from?